# Javascript form input field selection and AJAX

Tags: javascript, forms, dom

I think I want to do something simple, but I'm not sure how to execute it. I have been trying for hours now, with little luck.

```
function myFunc (form) {
    // determine currently selected field on form - Thank you James!
    var currElem = document.activeElement;
    myAJAX_request();  // This will regenerate the form (no field selected)
    // restore currently selected field on form
    currElem.focus();  // This does NOT work -- WHY?
    currElem.select();
}
```

I'm looking for a clean implementation that will use "document.forms..." to find the input fields, instead of having to put an id tag on every single form element. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use framework such as jQuery. jQuery has .serialize() method that should do exactly what you need. [Here it is](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: No, I'm afraid you've misunderstood my request. I don't particularly want to send the information across the AJAX request. The AJAX will refresh the content, then I want to access it with JavaScript and update the selected input field.

Comment: @zak you can still use jQuery for that. I'd read the jQuery selectors link that Shrinath gave you. (I didn't test but I assume it would work.) if you have a form "myform" and an input "myInput" then you could select the input something like `jQuery("form[name="myform"] input[name="myInput"])` the selectors are basically css selectors. EDIT: if you mean which element has focus its something like `document.activeElement`

Comment: Awesome comment! "document.activeElement" solves half my problem. It's read-only, so I need to know how to put the focus back to the same element after the AJAX call. Almost there!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `document.getElementByName`. I do assume you have names for your fields atleast, don't you ?   Store them in a variable/cookie and retrieve it back after your `myAjax_request()`.

and to make your life easier in future,

You could use other selectors of jquery, like name, class, etc.
Read about jQuery's selectors [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: I have the one function above processing several forms, and my "name" attributes have duplicates across the forms. I need a way to access the field by the form name, which is unique.

Comment: is iterating through elements using something like this is what you want? `document.forms.some_form.getElementsByTagName('input')`, returns all `<input>` elements from `<form name="some_form">`

Comment: jQuery supports child selectors, read this : http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/   Using which you could easily select a particular element of particular form